# High limit in Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm for finding prime numbers makes the program stop working

Tags: c, loops, runtime-error, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have used Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm to find the sum of prime numbers under certain limit and it has worked correctly until limit of 2 million, but when I tried 3 million the program has stopped while executing. Here is the code:

```
int main(){

    bool x[3000000];
    unsigned long long sum = 0;

    for(unsigned long long i=0; i< 3000000; i++)
        x[i] = true;

    x[0] = x[1] = false;

    for(unsigned long long i = 2; i < 3000000; i++){
        if(x[i]){
            for (unsigned long long j = 2; i * j < 3000000; j++) {
                x[j*i] = false;
            }
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    printf("%ld", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely `bool x[3000000];` will result in a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), as it will require more memory than is typically available on the stack . As a quick fix change this to:

```
static bool x[3000000];
```

or consider using dynamic memory allocation:

```
bool *x = malloc(3000000 * sizeof(*x));

// do your stuff

free(x);
```

---

Also note that your printf format specifier is wrong, since `sum` is declared as `unsigned long long` - change:

```
printf("%ld", sum);
```

to:

```
printf("%llu", sum);
```

If you're using a decent compiler (e.g. gcc) with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then the compiler should already have warned you about this error.

---

One further tip: don't use hard-coded constants like `3000000` - use a symbolic constant, and then you only have to define the value in one place - this is known as the "Single Point Of Truth" (SPOT) principle, or "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY):

```
const size_t n = 3000000;
```

and then wherever you are currently using `3000000` use `n` instead.

Comment: static has worked well .. but when I use symbolic constant like u did here, it give me an error : storage size of 'x' is not constant.

Comment: Oh - are you using a very old compiler ? In that case you might have to use `#define n 3000000` instead of `const size_t n = 3000000;`.

Comment: it sometimes with high limits give me negative numbers .. why is that ? for instance 4 millions limit outputs -959202331

Comment: Your printf format specifier is wrong: change `printf("%ld", sum);` to `printf("%llu", sum);`

Comment: thank u very much .. u just amazing :)
I wish u a nice day :)